# How do I call methods in a C# dll from my C code?

Tags: c#, c++, c

I am trying to create an integration between a 3rd party Lisp-based program (Let's call it ABC) and a C# program I have written myself (let's call it DEF).
The problem is that ABC can only call assemblies created in C or Fortran.
So I started learning C, and I got the "hello world" test to work, where ABC call my C dll and gets "hello world" in return.
The I tried to call my DEF dll from the C code using explicit loading and GetProcAddress. It worked if I called another C dll, but not a C# dll.
Now I wonder if I must learn C++ and call C# from C++ to create this nice call chain:

ABC -> C -> C++ -> DEF(C#) -> C++ -> C -> ABC

If that is the only way, can anyone help me with some examples etc?

Comment: Did you register your c# dll for COM interop? I've done it in the past, it is possible.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your question answered if it is (check the hook under the answer's downvote button).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [this project](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports) to export C# functions as native entry points.

Answer (score 3):

> When you create a .NET assembly, you can set a checkbox to have the
>   assembly registered for COM interop. This will allow you to access it
>   from any language that can call COM. (C can can't it? Been a long time
>   since I touched C or C++.)
>
> Configuration Properties -> Build page of your project properties.
>   Look for "Register for COM Interop".

Comment: This did not work. C still cannot find the procedure address in the dll.